# Gradlew Never Ending Busy Daemon Issue

Tags: gradle, daemon, gradlew

I'm pretty mad at this, I have reinstalled different versions of Gradle, tried multiple project building, but when I run gradlew ANYTHING or gradlew.bat files in any project, it gives me a never ending amount of busy daemons. Ex:

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 63 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 64 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 65 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 66 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 67 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 68 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 69 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 70 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 71 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 72 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 73 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 74 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 75 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 76 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 77 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 78 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 79 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 80 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 81 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 82 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 83 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 84 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 85 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 86 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 87 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 88 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 89 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 90 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 91 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 92 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 93 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

and it NEVER ends! I have no Idea why this is happening and I am just very confused. Any help would be appreciated.